# The dbContext entry State is changed automatically causing multiple reference exception

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbcontext

I'm trying to insert to database this class

```
public class InventoryItem {
    [Key]
    public int InventoryItemId { get; set; }

    public int InStockNumber { get; set; }

    public int InventoryItemTypeID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("InventoryItemTypeID")]
    public virtual InventoryItemType InventoryItemType { get; set; }
}
```

Second, after some business logic

```
   inventoryItem.InventoryItemType = itemTypesRepository.Find(243);
   inventoryItem.InventoryItemTypeId = 243;
```

After this I tried:
       context.InventoryItems.Add(inventoryItem); // yes InventoryItems are DbSet

But this causes a Multiple reference exception.
If I removed the set of navigation property InventoryItemType it runs ok. But I need it for other reasons.

So I tried to do some things manually

```
    var entry = context.Entry(inventoryitem);

    // New entity
    if (entry.State == EntityState.Detached)
    {
        entry.State = EntityState.Added;
    }
```

The problem is that the fact of do context.Entry automatically adds the entry and the line
       entry.State = EntitySate.Added

causes multiple reference exception.

I could rewrite the business logic to do not set the navigation property. But, Can anyone help me with another way to avoid this problem?

Comment: What is this supposed to do `inventoryItem.InventoryItemId = inventoryItem.InventoryItemTypeId`? You are setting the value of the primary key to the value of the foreign key pointing to another table. This doesn't look good.

Comment: @WiktorZychla sorry was a typing mistake. It is fixed now

Comment: I am confused by your question, it looks like you are trying to add an item to the context that you have just retrieved from the context. If you try to do that you will get an error.

Comment: @AlbertoLeón: looks even worse now, you are assigning the same field value to itself.

Comment: @Colin you're right... but the matter is that If I don't do it, the context didn't tracked the entity.

Comment: @WiktorZychla I need the navigation property in one way and in the other as a DTO meaning the foreign key. But yes, every time I look the code I unlike more it...

Comment: I think you need to clarify your question by showing the code that isn't working and the actual error messages you get. But, stabbing around in the dark, I wonder if this article might help: Why does Entity Framework Reinsert Existing Objects into My Database? msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn166926.aspx

Comment: Yes I readed this link before and it its what is happening. There is a big mistake in my hand. I mixed Entities and ViewModel concern and I'm paying my bad architecture... I can't provide the code because is very big and difficoult to see the bites of code with de problem.